# Get the position of the point that lies at 25% of a line?

Tags: geometry, line

I have a line with 2 points. I know the distance between the 2 points. I also calculated the angle of the line.

My target is to get a point that lies at 25% ot the line.

I calculate the y of this point with (dist/100)*25.

My only problem is calculating the x of the point. I suspect i have all the variables needed i only can't seem to find how to calculate the x. Does anybody know this?

Comment: You mean a segment. A line is infinite. Distance from where?

Comment: Including the information you have about the problem, including existing point coordinates or segment lengths would also help others answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a segment (not line) with endpoints P0 (coordinates x0,y0) and P1(x1,y1). New point P lies at this segment and distance |P0P| = 0.25 * |P0P1|, if their coordinates are:

```
x = x0 + 0.25 * (x1-x0)
y = y0 + 0.25 * (y1-y0)
```

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate your reply. I will try to convert your reply in to code.

Answer (score 0):

It's just simple vector maths, no need for any angles or trig here.

```
startPos = (0,0)
endPos = (10,10)

fratcion = 0.25

distX = endPos.x - startPos.x
distY = endPos.y - startPos.y

pos.x = startPos.x + fraction*distX
pos.y = startPos.y + fraction*distY
```